# How to find max from dynamic number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:
A: 20*15 matrix of numbers 
B: 20*1 list of numbers (from 1-15).

I would like to find the max number on each row in table A, however only looking at the columns from table B

Simplified example below.

Thanks!

```
+-----------------+
|       A:        |
+-----------------+
| 7  3  5  4      |
| 8  1  2  5      |
| 2  3  7  2      |
| 4  1  3  6      |


+-----------------+
|       B:        |
+-----------------+
| 2               |
| 4               |
| 1               |
| 2               |
```

---

```
| Desired result: |
| 7               |
| 8               |
| 2               |
| 4               |
```

Comment: A minimal code example would be nice, also to show that you've put some effort into discovering the solution yourself. Your example mockup isn't very helpful in understanding the question either, at least to me.

Comment: Question is unclear to me

Answer (score 3):

#### `where` + `max`

You want to find maximum value in the first `n` columns for each row, where `n` is from your second dataframe. So mask the cells that are not important then take the max as `max` ignores `NaN` by default.

```
import numpy as np

m = np.arange(dfa.shape[1]) < dfb[0][:, None]  # Thanks rafaelc
dfa.where(m).max(1)

#0    7.0
#1    8.0
#2    2.0
#3    4.0
#dtype: float64
```

---

Sample Data:

```
dfa
   0  1  2  3
0  7  3  5  4
1  8  1  2  5
2  2  3  7  2
3  4  1  3  6

dfb
   0
0  2
1  4
2  1
3  2
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `pd.DataFrame.where` and `np.ones`

```
m = np.ones(dfa.shape).cumsum(1)
dfa.where(m <= dfb.to_numpy()).max(1)
```

Can also use

```
m = np.broadcast_to(np.arange(len(dfa)) + 1, dfa.shape)
```

---

```
0    7.0
1    8.0
2    2.0
3    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

`pandas` solution

```
S=A.stack()
S[B.reindex(S.index.get_level_values(0)).values>=S.index.get_level_values(1)].max(level=0)
Out[276]: 
0    7
1    8
2    2
3    4
dtype: int64
```