# sum over columns using different length

Tags: pandas

I have a pd df.

The table looks like:

```
  df

      lifetime   0       1       2       3      4       5  ....  30
   0    2        0.12   0.14    0.18    0.12    0.13  0.14 ....  0.14
   1    3        0.12   0.14    0.18    0.12    0.13  0.14 ....  0.14
   2    4        0.12   0.14    0.18    0.12    0.13  0.14 ....  0.14
```

I want to sum the columns from 0 to 30 based on the column "lifetime" value, so the results looks like:

```
  df
     lifetime    Total
   0    2        sum(0.12+ 0.14) # sum column 0 and 1
   1    3        sum(0.12+0.14+0.18) #sum from column 0 to 2  
   2    4        sum(0.12+0.14+0.18+0.12+0.13) #sum from column 0 to 3
```

How can I do it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Super similar to this question from a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560377/how-to-find-max-from-dynamic-number-of-columns

Answer (score 2):

You can use `where` with broadcasting:

```
s = df.iloc[:,1:]
s.where(df.lifetime.to_numpy()[:,None] > np.arange(s.shape[1])).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
0    0.26
1    0.44
2    0.56
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the following function:

```
def mySum(row):
    uLim = int(row.lifetime) + 1
    return row.iloc[1:uLim].sum()
```

Then apply it and join the result with *lifetime* column:

```
df = df.lifetime.to_frame().join(df.apply(mySum, axis=1).rename('Total'))
```

The advantage over the other solution is that my solution creates
the target DataFrame, not only the new column.

Comment: Thank you for your help!